# Why is APP_DATA bundle not passed to search results activity on Android 4 when using voice search?

Tags: android, search, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, voice

I have a searchable app that works fine on Android 2.2.  I can search either by typing or by using voice search and the bundle that I pass to [`startSearch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startSearch%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20android.os.Bundle,%20boolean%29) is available in the intent extras in the search results activity (under the `SearchManager.APP_DATA` key).

However, when running this same app on a device running Android 4.0.4 (I've tried two different devices - one HTC and one Samsung) the bundle is only passed to the results activity when searching using the keyboard.  Using voice search it is missing.  I have confirmed that the bundle is being created and passed to `startSearch`.  It goes missing at some point after that.

For what it's worth, this is my `searchable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
            android:voiceLanguageModel="web_search"
            android:voiceLanguage="en">
</searchable>
```

And this is where I invoke `startSearch`:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested()
{
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putParcelable(URI_EXTRA, getIntent().getParcelableExtra(URI_EXTRA));
    data.putString(NAME_EXTRA, getIntent().getStringExtra(NAME_EXTRA));
    startSearch(null, false, data, false);
    return true;
}
```

In `onCreate` in the search results activity I attempt to retrieve the bundle as follows but it is null:

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getBundleExtra(SearchManager.APP_DATA);
```

Any ideas what might cause this or know how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue has been fixed in the android sources with the following commit https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/1bcfe84179417cda57176fe8661a4a749cb843b6